# Error in "interpolate" expressions when trying to change color according to multiple numbers in mapbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, interpolation, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have an example.geojson file in the same repository with my html file, formed like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
        {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [0.328475794345889,51.5430323219002],
                    [0.330011830097691,51.544575635037],
                    [0.332923372866699,51.5445177628264],
                    [0.334298679806651, 51.5429165836459],
                    [0.328475794345889,51.5430323219002]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {

            "NO2_mean": -1.47235050096324e-67                
        }
    }
 ] 
}
```

And I want to change the color regarding to the property: NO2_mean.

I have tried this

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my_access_token';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
  center: [-0.318092, 51.509865],
  zoom: 10
});

map.on('load', function() {
  map.addSource('london', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
        {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [0.328475794345889,51.5430323219002],
                    [0.330011830097691,51.544575635037],
                    [0.332923372866699,51.5445177628264],
                    [0.334298679806651, 51.5429165836459],
                    [0.328475794345889,51.5430323219002]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {

            "NO2_mean": -1.47235050096324e-67                
        }
    }
 ] 
}
  });

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'london-boundary',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'london',
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': [
        'interpolate', ['linear'],
        ['number', ['get', 'NO2_mean']],
        [ "<=" , 'number', 1], #2DC4B2',
        [ "<=" , 'number', 2], '#3BB3C3', 
        [ "<=" , 'number', 3],'#669EC4', 
        [ "<=" , 'number', 4], '#A2719B', 
        [ "<=" , 'number', 5], '#AA5E79'
      ],
      'fill-opacity': 0.8
    },
    'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']
  });

});
```

I got the error: Input/output pairs for "interpolate" expressions must be defined using literal numeric values (not computed expressions) for the input values.
    at Object.Mn [as emitValidationErrors] (validate_style.js:37)

[image]

What should I change in my html file? Any advice will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it and add relevant files in a [mcve]

Comment: I had to fix a few things - missing quotes and commas: `'fill-color': [
        'interpolate', ['linear'],
        ['number', ['get', 'NO2_mean']],
        [ "<=" , 'number', 1], 
        '#2DC4B2', [ "<=" , 'number', 2], '#3BB3C3', [ "<=" , 'number', 3],
        '#669EC4', [ "<=" , 'number', 4], '#A2719B', [ "<=" , 'number', 5], 
        '#AA5E79'
`

Comment: Does it work now with your access token?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The problem is with the syntax of the code in the fill-color area. It is not with the token. The code runs without the layer.

Comment: Does the fill color I fixed for you work now when you run the code above with your access token! I did not ask about the access token

Comment: PS: Don't post the token here. just test the code I changed

Comment: Aaa I am so sorry..I run it with the changes but didn't work.

Comment: At least it does not give any errors now

Comment: In the console I have an error 304 without a message.

Comment: Error 304?  Or status 304? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748391/why-mapboxgl-api-returns-304-status-code

Comment: I had a new error : Input/output pairs for "interpolation" expressions must be defined using literal numeric values (not computed expressions) for the input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
 map.addLayer({
    'id': 'london-boundary',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'london',
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': [
        'interpolate', ['linear'],
        ['number', ['get', 'NO2_mean']],
        1, #2DC4B2',
        2, '#3BB3C3', 
        3,'#669EC4', 
        4, '#A2719B', 
        5, '#AA5E79'
      ],
      'fill-opacity': 0.8
    },
    'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']
  });
```

The values 1 to 5 refer to the steps that the color of the polygon will change. In the interpolate expressions only int values are valid. 
If (n02_mean <= 1), then the color is #2DC4B2'.
If (1 < n02_mean <= 2), then the color is a mix of #2DC4B2' and '#3BB3C3', etc.